# how to increase days in date in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, variables

Nowadays I am working on laravel application. I am new on laravel and it is my first project. Can you guys please tell me how to increase days in date?

I have these 3 variables:

```
 $subscription['start_date'] = $dates['start'];
 $subscription['end_date'] = $dates['end'];
 $subscription['trial_end_date'] = $dates['trial'];
 start 
 end
 trial
```

start values are perfect but in end and trial I want date of 10 days later

Please help me, I'd be really thankful

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using the [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) PHP API date-time exstension.

If you want to add 10 days to your date, simply do this:

```
$subscription['trial_end_date']->addDays(10);
```

Or if your `trial_end_date` is not a `Carbon` instance, you can do this instead:

```
Carbon::parse($subscription['trial_end_date'])->addDays(10);
```

The method is the same for any of your dates. If you have any errors or need any more help, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `Carbon`, where you can easily handles tasks like this.

Example:

```
$subscription['trial_end_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('your-format-here', $dates['trial']);
$subscription['trial_end_date']->addDays(10);
```

Don't forget to import the correct Namespace on top

Answer (score 0):

Use Carbon\Carbon

```
$date = $your_desire->addDays($i);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is by using `Carbon`. [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) is a simple `php` Api extension for `Datetime`.

First you need to import carbon like so `use Carbon\Carbon;` which in built in `Laravel`.

Make `$subscription['start_date']` an instance of Carbon before using `addDays()`

```html
<?php

// Make $subscription['start_date'] an instance of Carbon before using addDays()
$trialends = Carbon::parse($subscription['start_date'])->addDays(10);
```